# binding image control to listbox selected item

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a listbox,inside that item template,and inside that data template(as usual). My aim
is- in listbox selection changed event, I want to bind listbox selected item to a image control-and my code is--

```
ListBox lb = (ListBox)sender;

ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)lb.SelectedItem;

Image im = (Image)item.Content;
Image1.Source = new BitmapImage(((BitmapImage)im.Source).UriSource);
```

and my `ListBox.ItemTemplate` looks like this:

```
<ListBox Name="imageList" Height="556" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}" SelectionChanged="imageList_SelectionChanged" >
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Image Source="{Binding Imgs}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

But it is showing exception. `Image1` is my image control and I don't want to bind image source in xaml. I have some certain requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have excepion because when you bind `ListBox`, and I assume you do, or any `ItemsControl` for that matter, properties like `Items`, `SelectedItem` and `SelectedItems` will be of a type of bound list item and not `ListBoxItem`, which is just a container. If you need `ListBoxItem` refer to it like that:

```
var listBox = sender as ListBox;
var lbi = (ListBoxItem)listBox
                         .ItemContainerGenerator
                         .ContainerFromItem(listBox.SelectedItem)
```

but if your `Image` is part of `DataTemplate` it won't be as easy as getting `Content`. Again it will be of a type of bound item, basically point to the same as `SelectedItem`. Maybe you can use that as otherwise you will need to refer to `VisualTreeHelper` as by default there will be other controls in visual tree between `ListBoxItem` and your `DataTemplate` `Image`. I undrestand you don't want to bind `Image.Source` but why not bind back `ListBox.SelectedItem` and then you can refer to your object instead.

If you want to update `Image1.Source` with `SelectedItem` image then your `SelectionChange` method should look like this:

```
Image1.Source = ((sender as ListBox).SelecteItem as img).Imgs;
```

Comment: Hey dkozi,Thanks for considering this question,but it did not helped me and it is giving same exception.And u r thinking perfectly I dont want to bind image.source.

Comment: What does your ListBox store? What is the type of the item that you bind to it? Is it URI or path to an image that you want to set as Source in your image?

Comment: Can you update the question with ListBox ItemTemplate and then I will be able to tell you what to do to set Image.Source properly?

Comment: actually in my listbox i have some images(only).by clicking image it have to show an enlarged image in a image control.And I dont want to bind this in xaml.pls help me.i am developing a photshop application.

Comment: when iam selecting from listbox it is showing perfectly an image control.but when iam adding effects in code behind,it is also showing effected image,but here iam setting image.source to writable image.after that when iam selecting image from listbox it is not getting and it is obvious also bcoz i have already set image.source to writable image(which has some pixel change).thats why i found a solution to set image source in listbox selection changed event.here iam facing challenge.

Comment: No problem just edit your question and past in your `ListBox` `ItemTemplate` then I will know what to look for

Comment: hey i have wriiten whole story.

Comment: Ok, but I still need your `ListBox` `ItemTemplate` to tell you how to solve your problem

Comment: <ListBox Name="imageList" Height="556" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}" SelectionChanged="imageList_SelectionChanged" >
                   
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>
                              <Image Source="{Binding Imgs}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                               
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>

Comment: new Uri(selItem.Imgs, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),

Comment: new BitmapImage(selItem.Imgs)

Comment: `MyItemType` needs to be replaced with a class name which exposes `Imgs` property, that you use in `DataTemplate` and then you need to choose depending on what is the type of `Imgs` property (not both of them, just one). What is the class name that holds `Imgs` property and what is the type of `Imgs` property?

Comment: hey do u have facebook account(tell what should i type in search box).i wanna chat with u

Comment: Just tell me what is the class name that holds `Imgs` property and what is the type of `Imgs` property? Better yet, past in that class definition into your question

Comment: Class name===img,and it is a type of bitmapimage

Comment: then try that `Image1.Source = ((sender as ListBox).SelecteItem as BitmapImage)`

Comment: `Imgs` may be of `BitmapImage` type, which makes sense, but it must be a public property of some outer class otherwise you would not be able to bind it, in your template, by that name. Until you tell me how that class looks like I will not be able to help you and we can guess forever.

Comment: public class img
        {
            public BitmapImage Imgs { get; set; }
        }

Comment: public void getImages()
        {
            MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
            var pictures = mediaLibrary.Pictures;
            foreach (var picture in pictures)
            {
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(picture.GetImage());
                img mediaImage = new img();
                mediaImage.Imgs = image;
                imageList.Items.Add(mediaImage);
            }
        }here is how iam binding

Comment: try that `Image1.Source = ((sender as ListBox).SelecteItem as img).Imgs`